Why do numpy float32s correctly return numbers below the float32 minimum value?
The smallest number that can be stored by an IEEE-754 32-bit float is 2^-126 ~ 1.18e-38. Why then do I get the following output?
print(np.float32(1e-39))
> 1e-39

Through experimentation, it looks like the smallest float that is actually truncated to 0 is around 1e-46. It is able to perform computation on these small numbers too. For example:
print(np.float32(2*1e-45))
> 2.802596928649634e-45

Obviously there is a very large truncation error here, but it is nevertheless clearly performing computation on these very small numbers. What's going on? Does the numpy float32 not conform to IEEE-754?

Why do you think 2^-126 is the smallest IEEE754 binary32 float?

1.18·10^−38 is the minimum normal number >0 for a 32-bit float.  1.40·10^−45 is the minimum subnormal number >0 (see the link and also IEEE 754).

Possible duplicate of how can smallest floating point number be 2^(-126) , not 2^(-128)? (See answers there.)

Worth remembering that subnormal numbers are much slower in arithmetic that normal floating point numbers. DAZ and FTZ can help with that see denormal flags. More detail on IEEE754 here

This question is similar to: how can smallest floating point number be 2^(-126) , not 2^(-128). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

2−126 is not the smallest number that can be stored in an IEEE-754 32-bit binary format (named binary32). It is the smallest positive normal number.
The smallest positive number the format can represent is 2−149.
In the 32-bit bit string binary32 uses to represent numbers, there is a one-bit sign field, S, an eight-bit exponent field, E, and a 23-bit trailing significand field, F.
0 in the S field denotes +, and 1 denotes −.
Taking the E and F fields as binary numerals:

If E = 0, the number represented is (−1)S•21−127•(0+F•2−23). These are subnormal numbers.

If 0 < E < 127, the number represented is (−1)S•2E−127•(1+F•2−23). These are normal numbers.

If E = 127, the value represented is either infinity (if F = 0) or a NaN (otherwise).


The minimum value for the positive normal numbers occurs when S = 0, E = 1, and F = 0, and we have (−1)0•21−127•(1+0•2−23) = 2−126.
The minimum value for the positive subnormal numbers occurs when S = 0, E = 0, and F = 1, and we have (−1)0•21−127•(0+1•2−23) = 2−126•2−23 = 2−149. (Observe this cases has F = 1 because F = 0 would produce 0, and the represented value would not be positive.)
Subnormal numbers are specified as part of the format to provide gradual underflow. For any two numbers representable in the format, a and b, then, if a ≠ b, the result of performing a subtraction in the format is always non-zero. If subnormal numbers were not part of the format and a and b were very small normal numbers, then a−b might not be representable in the format because it is below the normal range. Without subnormal numbers, some of these results would round to 0.
Also note 2−149 is not the lowest value the format can represent. It is the lowest positive value. If you do not restrict it to positive values, the lowest value the format can represent is either 0 (lowest in magnitude) or −∞ (lowest absolutely).
